# Getting error when starting to use spring boot 3 in my project that uses camel

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel, spring-boot-3

When compiling the project everything goes well, but i have this error when it starts:

```
2023-12-27 12:54:53,892 ERROR [marker:] [           main] [correlationId:] o.s.b.SpringApplication.824: Application run failed 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
    - org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration
```

Everything was working fine with spring 2 but now i have to upgrade it and is giving me the error.
Application class has this config:

```
@SpringBootApplication(
    exclude = {
      CamelAutoConfiguration.class,
      org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
      org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet
          .ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class
    })
```

I try to remove that config but when i do that spring does not find beans that are defined in the xml file, throwing this error:

```
2023-12-27 12:33:10,875 ERROR [marker:] [           main] [correlationId:] o.s.b.SpringApplication.824: Application run failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:/applicationContextDefault.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
```